# How to describe a person who is good at his job and therefore everybody needs him?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am looking for a word to describe a person who is good at his job and therefore everybody needs him.

Is it 'needed' or 'needful'? What about 'indispensable'?

Comment: If you mean "and therefore everybody needs his help", then I would question how good the person is at his job.  He might be doing his job in a way that prevents (or discourages) other people from learning how to do their jobs.

Comment: Oops. I misspelled 'his' and 'him'. I am not very familiar with Indian English. What I meant is everybody needs him because if he quits, it would be very hard to find a person that does the job equally good.

Comment: Sounds like me ...

Comment: Tip for all English language learners:  The word is *never* `needful`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indispensable is a good choice.

> His knowledge of human nature, inexhaustible energy, dauntless self-confidence and diplomatic finesse **made him indispensable** to Gustavus III. 
>   <sup>[Source](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/indispensable)</sup>

Also, essential, crucial, vital, or key.

> She is **a crucial member** of our team and would be difficult to replace.

None of these words are specific to a person who is good at their work - they can be used for anything that is very important. I've chosen the ones that I see most often in business communications - there are other synonyms for indispensable that would work as well.

We could probably narrow it down even more if you provided an example sentence to show how you would like to use this word. I asked my husband what words he would choose, and he said "under-paid", "over-qualified", and possibly "over-worked" (as a joke).